# Magento 1.6 Soap v2 attributes and additional attributes

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am working with Magento 1.6 and try to call the Soap API V2 to get product-information (attributes and additional attributes).

If use soapUI or try to generate a request in java to get information of the product and its additional attributes a new entry gets written to the system log, saying:

```
2012-01-20T08:33:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): array_merge() [<a href='function.array merge'>function.array-merge</a>]: Argument #2 is not an array/opt/website/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
```

So I neither get those attributes nor can I update these on a product.

Does anybody have idea to come over this issue!

thanks

Comment: could you show your code to get the product information from magento?

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured it out!

There seems to be a "bug" in that file! So if you request only one attribute the array_merge() function can't join the variable because the $attribute variable is not an array.

Try to send multiple attributes with soaoUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:catalogProductInfoRequestParam>
             <sessionId>b595ed396f1901142cb284e4c280df82</sessionId>
             <productId>7271</productId>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <store>0</store>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <attributes>
                <additional_attributes>
            <complexObjectArray>atribute</complexObjectArray>
            <complexObjectArray>atribute</complexObjectArray>
            <complexObjectArray>atribute</complexObjectArray>
            <complexObjectArray>atribute</complexObjectArray>
            <complexObjectArray>atribute</complexObjectArray>
                </additional_attributes>
             </attributes>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <identifierType/>
          </urn:catalogProductInfoRequestParam>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: FABULOUS!  This just saved me a bunch of time (already spent too long on this one)....thanks a ton!